# http: Unable to import http dependency in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, https

I have added the dependency in the pubspec.yaml flie as:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.5
```

And afterward had also run the command **flutter packages get **

Even after this I am unable to import its package in my main.dart file.

```
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
```

Have added this line in my main.dart file but still getting the error and unable to use http methods in my code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site.

Comment: You should be running `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your IDE and Run the Following command:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```